# matplotlib barchart: How to spread bars evenly in a postgres-generate_series?

Tags: postgresql, matplotlib, bar-chart, psycopg2

I'm creating an barchart with matplotlib and connecting to a postgres database with psycopg2.

The data I want to plot in the barchart is comming from a postgres database with following SQL:

```
SELECT  
(to_char(serie,'yyyy'))::text::int AS Year,  
sum(amount)::numeric::int AS eintraege   
FROM ( SELECT...) ... ;
```

"serie" in the sql stands for an generate_series from 2006 to 2012. This code is within my python-script to plot the result:

```
plt.bar(year, count, align='center')  
fig.autofmt_xdate()  
plt.xticks(year, (year))  
plt.xlabel('year')  
plt.ylabel('V1M0')
```

This leads to this plot:

[image]

So far I get what I expect to get :-)

But if I expand my generate_series (to_char(serie,'yyyy') in the sql above so it not only gives me the years but also the months ((to_char(serie,'yyyymm') the plot looks somehow weird:

[image]

I get the impression the bars are grouped by year as I've got only one entry for 2006 (december 2006) in my db but for 2007 every month has a value.

So my question: How can I resolve a plot with evenly spread bars (like in the first plot). Am I missing something? I searched the web for several hours but I couldn't find a hint or solution to my problem.

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Please show your SQL. The full SQL, not just a snippet. Both the working (years only) one, and the years-and-months one. If possible, some sample data and table definitions would be nice too, or at least the output of the queries before graphing.

Comment: I found a workaround to the problem but as a newbie on stackoverflow I have to wait 8 hours to answer my own question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not found the actual reason for this behaviour but a workaround:
    SELECT
    (to_char(serie,'yyyymm'))::text AS Year,
    sum(amount)::numeric::int AS eintraege
    FROM ( SELECT...) ... ;
Do not cast the generate_series back to an integer but leave the column formatted as a string. Then for plotting, calculate the length of the string in "plt.xticks"

```
plt.bar(range(len(count)), count, align='center', label='Anzahl an erstellten Objekten')
fig.autofmt_xdate()  
plt.xticks(range(len(count)), (year)) 
plt.xlabel('year')  
plt.ylabel('V1M0')
```

Now the plot looks good (never mind the axis-labeling, this can be changed later on).
http://geospatialview.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Histogramm_komisch_geloest.png